# Why does the audioRecorderDidFinishRecording function not work?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am developing an iOS app. (iOS 11.2)
I am developing audio recording and moving to another view when I press STOP.
But the following function is not working.
(audioRecorderDidFinishRecording)

I tried Google search, but I am wandering a lot in short English skills.
Please give a lot of advice.

```
class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

    @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        recordButton.isEnabled = true
        recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"
        audioRecorder.stop()
//        audioRecorder = nil
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)
        // performSegue(withIdentifier: "stopRecording", sender: audioRecorder.url)
    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "stopRecording", sender: audioRecorder.url)
        } else {
            print("recording was not successful")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it is highly likely that you have not assigned the delegate for `AVAudioRecorder`.

Wherever you are initialising your instance of `AVAudioRecorder`, underneath it try:

```
audioRecorder.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

[I found helpful answers during the search.](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/audiorecorderdidfinishrecording-cannot-get-called/165121/4?u=kji0205vpnx)